# Ember Engine Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-views/views/select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-addons, ember-engines

Created new app with

> ember new app-name
>
> version: 1.13.13
>
> node: 5.5.0
>
> npm: 2.14.10
>
> os: linux x64

After running

> "ember s"

App works proper in browser

As per guide at  https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines for running ember engine ran below command

> ember install ember-engines
>
> rm -rf bower_components
>
> bower install --save ember#canary #Choosed ember#canary from prompt
>
> bower install

And now when i do "ember s" app gets compile properly in CLI but app gets crash in browser and i see nothing in browser.

In console i see below error message

> Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-views/views/select

Tried debugging it, Could not find solution. Is i am missing somthig basic here ?

**Note :: I am new to ember. I think this would be small one but could not find solution on web as well.**

Comment: Are you using Ember.Select in your code? It has been removed in 2.0.

Comment: No, not using  Ember.Select . Just created new app and add steps for ember engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about that! There were a few commits/fixes on master that hadn't been released yet.

I just released v0.2.1 which should clear this up for you.