# Ember Could not find module ember-metal/streams/utils

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

Created new app with

> ember new app-name

Output from ember version --verbose:

> ember-cli: 2.5.0
>
> http_parser: 2.7.0
>
> node: 6.2.1
>
> v8: 5.0.71.52
>
> uv: 1.9.1
>
> zlib: 1.2.8
>
> ares: 1.10.1-DEV
>
> icu: 57.1
>
> modules: 48
>
> openssl: 1.0.2h
>
> os: linux x64

After running

> "ember s"

App works proper in browser

As per guide at  https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines for running ember engine ran below command

> ember install ember-engines
>
> rm -rf bower_components
>
> bower install --save ember#canary #Choosed ember#canary from prompt
>
> bower install

And now when i do "ember s" app gets compile properly in CLI but app gets crash in browser and i see nothing in browser.

In console i see below error message

> ember.debug.js:58Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-metal/streams/utils

**Note :: Faced a same for ember-views/views/select but got solved by Robert Jackson answeron my question. The question was posted at [Ember Engine Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-views/views/select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935714/ember-engine-uncaught-error-could-not-find-module-ember-views-views-select).**

I am tryingto figure out is this a problem with version I am using. Anybody faced  same problem can help.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of Ember CLI in that application. Tried re-initing and upgrading all of dependencies and it worked

Thanks to @nathanhammond for help at https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6063